# Script from https://account-d.docusign.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/oauth/token was blocked due to mime type mismatch

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to obtain the Access Token by passing authcode by calling rest api but my response was blocked saying mime type mismatch. PFB sample code

$.ajax({ 
        async: true,  // Async by default is set to “true” load the script asynchronously
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    redirect_uri: 'https://hclo365.sharepoint.com/sites/wf13test',
    data: 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0%2EAQkAAAABAAYABwCAGYGDcLfWSAgAgKUHy3C31kgCAONnoYIaQgFOsTImy5_ryv0VAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAdAAAADQAkAAAAMzRkYTY1NDktMTdjMC00MTM3LWE3YWEtYWJkYWMzNjQ0YWMzNwCWbGY1cO_JQKSrZRKWhxjbMACAZ4tNZ7fWSA%2Eaz__M8ULm--8DgmUspzcA1wa7soxB0jQgnKhIwKhRT4jDsmsmIa755xPK7sD1vKmeMM4LDISN1XignVCii1IecpEWO6PWR8gq6UToJG6DnKcPurKWXEwZblsyxf2kOXR1RtDQoev5_VxkqLKTT9rHCFB01eZzTir8SVMs5BPOWdCCufMok-lVyJoq5VRL2YoPB3iOhz8MZAVlElx0srIJJWUuHiXRImmU13__3qtRf82Kxattt_6cN8IcW9rjZDYB0dfcqIKon_Q27Fp8KYU4LEpYHVunKEli60dzWliTFX34KRGJYVpYqK-Zd6OyHuqculMPE6mctVlQbcG1DD3gQ',
        url: "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token",   // URL to fetch data from sharepoint list
        method: "POST",  //Specifies the operation to fetch the list item

```
    headers: {  
    Authorization : "Basic MzRkYTY1NDktMTdjMC00MTM3LWE3YWEtYWJkYWMzNjQ0YWMzOjgzNmQxNmZiLWU1MDctNDM2Ny04Y2ZlLTFiODkzOGU2MTE5Yw==",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'application/json', 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",   //It defines the Data format
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   //It defines the content type as JSON

    },     
    success: function(data) {              
      console.log('works'); 

    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));     
    }    
})
```

Looking for the possible solution for this to capture the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can call DS API from AJAX calls, you will be getting CORS issue. [DS Dev Blog1](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-single-page-applications-with-docusign-and-cors-part-1/), [DS Dev Blog2](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-single-page-applications-with-docusign-and-cors-part-2/) and [DS Dev Blog3](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-spas-cors-react-part-3/) explain how you can achieve Single Page Applications with DocuSign.